# Conditional formatting does not respect the range of application - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

The range of application of conditional formatting with custom formula is set for the whole row, but only the first column is highlighted. For some reason, when adding more columns to the spreadsheet, the conditional formatting works normally. What causes this?

The conditional formatting formula returns positive if there are duplicate rows:
=COUNTIFS($B$1:B;$B1;$C$1:C;$C1;$D$1:D;$D1;$E$1:E;$E1;$F$1:F;$F1;$G$1:G;$G1)>1

[No new columns added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDdJ6.png)

[5 columns added to the right and same "Apply to range"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POjWH.png)

I added new columns and it started working normally, but I don’t want these extra columns. Is there another solution?

Comment: why did you hide the screenshots again after I edited your post? I don't think most people want to click a link to see the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try locking all the columns:

```cpp
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B;$B1;$C$1:$C;$C1;$D$1:$D;$D1;$E$1:$E;$E1;$F$1:$F;$F1;$G$1:$G;$G1)>1
```